# Mapping column value based on another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am trying to change column value depends from the other column along its row then merge it to an existing excel file using the `ADSL` column as my key.

I have a Data like this:

```
ADSL     Status     Result
2/134    WO         No Server Answer
1/239    WO         Faulty
2/94     FA         Number
2/321    SP         Voltage
```

This is an actual data, the `Status` column has three possible value [WO, FA, SP] each value has equivalent `Result` value.

example:

```
Status                  Equivalent Result Value

                        Battery Tone
                        Engage
  WO                    No Dial Tone
                        No Server Answer
                        No Voltage
                        Number
```

---

```
  SP                    Voltage
```

---

```
  FA                    Faulty
                        Vacant
```

now in reality the `Status` column is not getting the right value based on its equivalent `Result` value.
(see data above)

What I'm trying to do is to correct the `status` value based on its equivalent value from `Result` column

what is the easiest or efficient way to do this in python? I am not looking on a particular library tho. any help would be appreciated a lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I believe need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
df2['Status'] = df2['Status'].map(df1.set_index('Result')['Status'])
```

If some values are not match is possible replace by original non `NaN`s values:

```
df2['Status'] = df2['Status'].map(df1.set_index('Result')['Status']).fillna(df2['Status'])
```